# Is there a way to remove 2 words from a sentence only if they occur consecutively?

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, nltk

I am trying to remove words from a dataframe column only if the two words occur consecutively.

| text | user |
| --- | --- |
| boy live on island | user1 |
| mall on the street boy live go | user2 |

in the above example, I'd like to remove the words **boy** and **live** if they occur consecutively to obtain output as follows:

| text | user |
| --- | --- |
| on island | user1 |
| mall on the street go | user2 |

I am using nltk stopwords to remove stopwords. But I think it can only contain single words.

Comment: What about `replace('boys live', '')`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the approach using `str.replace`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': ['boy live on island', 'mall on the street boy live go'],
    'user': ['user1', 'user2']
})
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('boy live','')
print (df)
```

Output:

```
text   user
0               on island  user1
1  mall on the street  go  user2
```